# How can I use the queryBuilder with formBuilder in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, query-builder, formbuilder

I have difficulties with the use of the query builder in Symfony.
Like this, my select box lists all data that is stored in my entity "Options":

```
$options['class'] = Options::class;
$options['choice_label'] = function ($value) {
    return $value->getName();
};

$formBuilder->add($name, $class, $options);
```

But I want to filter the data, so that the options show only the data that is connected to a specific id of my entity "Fields".

This is my approach with query builder:

```
$options['class'] = Options::class;
$options['choice_label'] = 'id';
$options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $id) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->leftJoin('f.fields', 'fi')
        ->where(":id MEMBER OF f.fields")
        ->setParameter(':id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
};
```

The error message I get is:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Controller\PagesController::App\Controller{closure}() must be an
>   instance of App\Controller\EntityRepository, instance of
>   App\Repository\OptionsRepository given, called in
>   /Users/work/project/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Form/Type/EntityType.php
>   on line 32

Comment: Change typehint?

Comment: Have you imported the EntityRepository into the class containing that form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with fact that `EntityRepository` is core Doctrine repository that is under 
`Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;` namespace. I also **doubt** that you have another `EntityRepository` in your project.

So, first error is in incorrect type hint. You should add `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;` before your controller. `OptionsRepository` will fit this definition as it extends `EntityRepository`, or at least, it **should**.

Second error is `->setParameter(':id', $id)` - you cannot set **repository** as parameter of a query, it's useless. I don't know what is `$id` but as with any other callback functions, you can `use` it.

And third, as option is named `query_builder` - your callback should return `QueryBuilder`, so remove `->getQuery()->execute();`.

In the end the proper code should be:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

//....

$options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $er) use ($id) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->leftJoin('f.fields', 'fi')
        ->where(":id MEMBER OF f.fields")
        ->setParameter(':id', $id);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me very much in the confusion. I did what you suggested. I still have an error now `Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given` I have to figure out, how to solve it and let you know as soon as I have solution

Comment: I had to remove the last two lines `->getQuery()
        ->execute();` and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Also check your entity has the **repositoryClass** properly set if you inject the entire repository.

Entity

```
/**
 * Category.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
...
}
```

Then

```
$builder->add('categories', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Category::class,
    'query_builder' => function (CategoryRepository $categoryRepository) {
        return $categoryRepository->getQueryBuilderForProductCreation();
     },
    'choice_label' => 'name',
]);
```